# How to add list items for a combo box

Tags: c#

I have tried to create items for a combo box but it is not working.Please help me out.
This is what i have so far;

```
private void cb_avg_weeks_month_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cb_avg_weeks_month.Items.Add('1');
    cb_avg_weeks_month.Items.Add('2');
    cb_avg_weeks_month.Items.Add('3');
}
```

Note:
`cb_avg_weeks_month` describes the name i have assigned to my combo box.

Comment: "Not working" is **no** appropriate error description.

Comment: ASP.NET? WinForms? WPF? Which specific combobox are you using?

Answer (score 4):

Well if you're only adding items to your combo box when the selected index has changed, then it'll never run because there aren't any items for the user to change the index on.

Populate your combo-box in your form's constructor after `InitializeComponent();`

Comment: Yep, I was about to say the same!

Comment: Thanks for you help but still i cannot get it.Please explain further.

Comment: You'll need to explain more about what you're doing, first. Can you edit your question to show what you're doing (code, etc), and also answer n8wrl's question on what technology you're using?

Comment: Am using c sharp and i want create combo box to list down the days in a week.

Answer (score 0):

if you work in Visual Studio you can add items to comboBox using comboBox's property.
if you want to do it using code, you can do it in constructor:

```
public Form1()
{
   cb_avg_weeks_month.Items.Add('1');
   cb_avg_weeks_month.Items.Add('2');
   cb_avg_weeks_month.Items.Add('3');
}
```